# Select drop down value in PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to select the values from the drop down list in the pdf using itextsharp but not able to. Can anyone help as how to select values from dropdown present in the pdf using c#.

Comment: How is the drop-down element built? Does it rely on JavaScript? Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: i don't think so that it include javascript behind it. Can you please check the pdf and let me know the approach if possible.

Comment: please find the link of pdf.                          
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rGEYhKGqodOckoxNqN1dCqesu-IFWun0

Comment: Ah, it's even worse than JavaScript, that form is not an AcroForm form (which is the native PDF form format) but an XFA form (which use PDFs only as an envelope). iText (and most other PDF libraries) have at best a limited XFA support only, e.g. limited to AcroForm/XFA hybrid forms, but you have a pure XFA form.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Do you think this pdf can be automated. This pdf is coming from Singapore government. so is there is a chance that they have restricted the access to this pdf.

Comment: Probably using some Adobe software. But I don't know Adobe's software well enough to tell which.